# Display fa icon as a button text in laravel form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

```
@can('user-delete')
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endcan
```

I need to display fa icon instead of DELETE text in the button,

```
<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
```

How can I display this fa icon in that button.

I'm using laravel and bootstrap 4.

Comment: @Remul Tried. But it just showing the, <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> as a plain text in the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Form::button` instead of `Form::submit` to achieve this:

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
```

Then you can simply add the `type` to `submit` to the button instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
    {!! Form::button('name if you need', array('class' => 'form-control') ) !!}
</div>
```

into your `Form::button array` you can use everything you need such as `'type'=>'submit'`